# How to embed an angular site using object tag in normal HTML?

Tags: html, angular

I am trying to display Angular website inside another website using object tag.I tried it using embed,iframe also,here i am not prefering iframe.

Here is my code

```
<object type="text/html" data="http://localhost:4200/auth/user-details/step1" width="800px" height="600px" style="overflow:auto;border:5px ridge blue">
</object>
```

IE11 and FireFox not showing  anything.
Working in chrome.

I tried the following code and get solved in firefox but not in IE11

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html>

<head> <meta charset="utf-8"/>   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://danml.com/js/download.js"></script> </head>

<body>   <h1>Main ad</h1>   <ad-holder url="http://localhost:4200/"  width="800px" height="600px" ></ad-holder>




  <script>
    $('ad-holder').each(function() {
      var $object = $(document.createElement('object'));
      $object.attr('data', 'http://localhost:4200/');
      $(this).append($object);
    });   </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Is there any other method to implement this?

Comment: can you add a reproducable demo? It's hard to understand from just the question you mentioned.

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<object type="text/html" data="http://localhost:4200/auth/user-details/step1" width="800px" height="600px" style="overflow:auto;border:5px ridge blue">
    </object>
</body>
</html>`    **The data in the object can be any angular website**  @AakashKumar

Comment: In Firefox, can you check by just loading http://localhost:4200 but not with /auth/user-details/step1?  Can you also check the Network tab in all three browsers?

Comment: In all the three browsers localhost:42000 is working. this object tab cant load the data in IE and firefox. @AakashKumar

Comment: Akshaya, I mean, in object tag in data attribute, only pass localhost:4200 and then check in Firefox and IE.